# ffmpeg screencapture with xvfb displaying green screen

Tags: javascript, ffmpeg, xvfb

Using xvfb to run a browser window and want to do a screen recording of that Doing

```
xvfb-run Firefox http://google.com
ffmpeg -y -r 30 -f x11grab -i :94.0 output.mp4
```

Getting output as if colors are washed out

Comment: Is it washed out or green screen?

Comment: Washed out screen http://dev.rocketium.com/images/561796c9ce0203f33fe8e565/thumbnail/1465638853621.png

Comment: That's not washed out - that looks like mismatch of pixel format - either channel order or endianness. Share your full console output of command.

Comment: You can check the log [here](http://pastebin.com/SnjK4ZQu)

Comment: You will have to tell `xfvb` to use a 24-bit display. Don't use xfvb, so can't help you with that.

Comment: Ok will see this option while running xvfb thanks

Comment: Using this option while starting xvfb works  Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x24+32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using this option while starting xvfb works

```
Xvfb :1 -screen 0 1600x1200x24+32
```

Comment: I get a green screen what could be the reason?

Comment: The problem i faced was because of 8 bit-display after starting xvfb with 32 bit display as above it worked fine